# what is the causes of Exhausted 2 retries in sidekiq.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

On my sidekiq.log I have a warn message `WARN: {:message=>"Exhausted 2 retries"}`. I would like to know how to fix that issues.

[complete gist](https://gist.github.com/guinslym/f1c932cec9e7ae283ed0) at line 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

> EXECABORT Transaction discarded because of previous errors.

Your Redis instance is broken somehow, most likely out of memory.

Comment: thanks I increased it to 22MB. Details of how-to. I had to set the maxmemory to 23068672 in sudo vim /etc/redis/6379.conf